# LUA pattern matching not working as intended

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

I am working on a LUA script that is meant to block all lines containing the string "@7.7.7.7" in any part of the incoming data.
For this the following regex has been used:

```
local reg = regex.new("555d%|@7\.7\.7\.7\\b\|abc.com")
```

While this does block @7.7.7.7, it is also blocking @757.787.84.91
I researched on Lua programming language and it showed that % (and not ) is the escape character for the magic character . (dot)
Therefore in the pattern "555d%|@7.7.7.7\b|", \ is not having any effect and . is taken to match any character.
However strangely, when I replace \ with %, it is not blocking a line containing "@7.7.7.7". 
The new pattern is as follows:

```
local reg = regex.new("555d%|@7%.7%.7%.7\\b|")
```

Could anyone assist me in knowing what could be the reason for this?

Comment: What library are you using? If you want to use Lua patterns, `@7.7.7.7` can be matched with `@7%.7%.7%.7%f[%D]`. If it is [Iceberg with *Oniguruma* regex](https://github.com/yuin/iceberg/blob/master/src/ib_regex.h), you need `"555d%\\|@7\\.7\\.7\\.7\\|"` (if `|` are literal symbols).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually these are pre-written scripts and this is my first brush with Lua. Therefore I am not sure which library is being used though I think it is based on PCRE.

Comment: What is your real input? I mean, what is the exact literal string you need to *match*? Note that `[[...]]` in Lua are like raw string literals in Python, the ``\`` is not treated as an escape sequence char. Does moteus's answer work for you? Then accept it.

Comment: Input that should get blocked: <user:12345678@7.7.7.7> Input that should not get blocked: <user:12345678@757.787.66.88>

Comment: Then you need `"@7(?:\\.7){3}\\b"`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for looking into this. Moteus's answer worked for me with minimal changes. Have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem because sequence `\.` inside string is escaping char.
On Lua 5.1 is equal just to `.` but no Lua > 5.1 and on LuaJIT it produce error like `invalid escape sequence near '\.'`.
So `"555d%|@7\.7\.7\.7\\b|"` equal to `"555d%|@7.7.7.7\\b|"`.
And this pattern (assume it is PCRE compatiable) match to `@757.787`
Next. Last pipe char in pattern allows match to empty string.
So nearly every string match to this pattern.
Also `d%` in PCRE equal to `d%`.
So I think you need pattern like

```
local reg = regex.new([[555d%|@7\.7\.7\.7\b]]")
-- or if you need pipe as last char in string
local reg = regex.new([[555d%|@7\.7\.7\.7\b\|]]")
```

Which means match to `555d%` or `@7.7.7.7`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The last pipe was incorrectly inserted. However I am a bit confused here. Do you mean that when put inside string '\' will not have any effect but inside brackets it will work as a escape character. The only change I see is replacing quotes with brackets.

Comment: you can escepe `\` chars as `"555d%|@7\\.7\\.7\\.7\\b"`

Comment: I am curious about one thing. While "555d%|@7\\.7\\.7\\.7\\b" works just fine, why does "555d%|@7%.7%.7%.7\\b" does not work when Lua programming manual says "The character `%´ works as an escape for those magic characters. So, '%.' matches a dot".